# Strangely abbreviated Russian BibTeX entry name

Tags: bibtex, cyrillic

I have following BibTeX entry:

```
@MISC{KaraMurzaBatchikovGlazyev2002,
author       = {Кара-Мурза, Сергей Георгиевич and Батчиков, С. А. and Глазьев, Сергей Юрьевич}, 
title        = {Белая книга. Экономические реформы в России 1991-2001}, 
year         = {2002}, 
url          = {http://bit.ly/1lpALQZ}
}
```

Here's the transliterated version:

```
@MISC{KaraMurzaBatchikovGlazyev2002,
author       = {Kara-Murza, Sergey Georgievich and Batchikov, S. A. and Glazyev, Sergey Yurevich}, 
title        = {Belaya kniga. Ekonomicheskie reformy v Rossii 1991-2001}, 
year         = {2002}, 
url          = {http://bit.ly/1lpALQZ}
}
```

I expected the abbreviated name of that entry to be something like `Кара-Мурза et al. (2002)` (`Kara-Murza et al. (2002)`), but it is rendered as `[Кара-Мурза et al.(2002)Кара-Мурза, Батчиков, and Глазьев]` (`Kara-Murza et al. (2002)Kara-Murza, Batchikov, Glazyev`).

[image: Bibliography]

How should I change the BibTeX and/or the LaTeX file in order for the abbreviated version to appear as either

1. `Кара-Мурза et al. (2002)` or
2. `Кара-Мурза, Батчиков, and Глазьев (2002)`

?

Here's the start of the document:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\linespread{1.05} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}

\title{...}
\author{Дмитрий Писаренко} 
\date{\today} 


\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Приложения}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Приложения}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{cover/2014_01_11_sviz_cover.pdf}

\input{titlepage}


\tableofcontents

\input{_text}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With a downsized example I simply get “[Кара-Мурза et al., 2002]” Please, make a self-contained minimal example.

Comment: @egreg You can find the source code of a minimal example as well as the result of compilation (on ShareLatex.com) at http://bit.ly/1ge00Rr .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not loading `natbib` and use `plainnat` that's specifically tailored for that package.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{KaraMurzaBatchikovGlazyev2002}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look at the manual of `natbib` for other citation commands (`\citep` and `\citet`, in particular).